# Downgrade MVC project from dotnetcore2.1 to dotnet framework 4.61

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-4.0

We need to downgrade an MVC project from .netcore to .netframework. For this matter I changed all *.csproj
files and replaced

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
with
 <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>.
```

when I run the project I do not see any error but as I call any of APIs I get the following exception:

```
Exception from request 'GET /launch'. Response status code is 500 InternalServerError. Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.BuildModel()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.get_ActionDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AttributeRoute.GetTreeRouter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AttributeRoute.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Ipi.Common.AspNetCore.FaultHandlingMiddleware.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext()
```

I believe there is an assembly missing but do not know where and how to get the version of the assembly which is causing the issue.

Comment: I'm not even sure that's possible... [Net Core is not the same thing as Net Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server)

Comment: This isn't a "downgrade". It's switching frameworks completely. You can't just replace the target framework - the project structures, startup code, and all sorts of other things are totally different between .NET Framework and .NET Core. Better to create a new project and then port any code you can across to the new project, and re-write anything that's framework-specific.

Comment: P.S. Why do you need to do this though? It's an unusual problem. Maybe you should think about resolving the root cause of this requirement, rather than trying to port code from a new framework to an older one.

Comment: Did you ensure all of your dependencies have a .net framework equivalent?  Can you do a dotnet restore and it succeed?    I fully agree with ADyson, you aren't "downgrading" but completely changing platforms and I can't imagine a reason behind why you would need or want to do this.